# How to open file from php code inside html file

Tags: php, html, ini

I have ".html" file and inside it I run php code. The php code should open ".ini" file.

```
".ini" file:
blast+: blast+\bin

blastn: test_na_db => Nucleotide test database
blastp: test_aa_db => Protein test database
blastx: test_aa_db => Protein test database
tblastn: test_na_db => Nucleotide test database
tblastx: test_na_db => Nucleotide test database


".html" file:
<td valign=top>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Database(s)</td>
<td>
<?php
$fp = fopen ("./filename.ini", "r");
if(!$fp) {
    echo "<p><strong> Error: Couldn't open file filename.ini </strong></p></body></html>";
    exit;
}
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $blastdbstring = rtrim(fgets($fp));
    if (!$blastdbstring) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^\s*#/", $blastdbstring)) {
        $blastdbArray = preg_split('/:/', $blastdbstring);  
        $blastProgram = $blastdbArray[0];
        $dbString = $blastdbArray[1];

        if ($blastProgram == "blast+") {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name= 'blastpath' value='$dbString'>";
        }else {
            if (preg_match("/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/", $blastProgram, $match)) {
                $blastProgram = $match[1];
            }
            if (preg_match("/^\s*(.*?)(\s*|\s*,\s*)$/", $dbString, $match)) {
                $dbString = $match[1];
            }
            $dbString = preg_replace("/\s*=>\s*/", "=>", $dbString);
            if (preg_match("/,/", $dbString, $match)) {
                $dbString = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", $dbString);
            }       
            echo "<input id='$blastProgram' type='hidden' name='blastdb[]' value='$dbString'>";
        }
    }   
}
fclose($fp);

?>
<select id="dbList" size=4 multiple="multiple" name ="patientIDarray[]">
<script type="text/javascript">
    here call js function that create options depend on the selection of previous question
</script>

</select>
</td>
```

Each time I got this error message: 
Couldn't open file filename.ini!!!!

".html" file and ".ini" file are in the same directory.

I have full control on that ".ini" file

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_file_fopen

Comment: Why dont you try to rename your index.html file to index.php?

Comment: I rename it to .php and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permission of the file, it may be not accessible to all.

please run "chmod 666 filename.ini"

Comment: If you are on Linux, use shell change directory to your web directory, it can be /var/www/html or /var/www, and run that command, if you are on windows just open the folder in your explorer, right click it, and share it with everyone. If you are somewhere on shared hosting, using cpannel's file explorer you can do it.

Comment: can you tell me how are you running it? directly, using CLI or through apache? and on which OS?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and right click on the file and give full control permission to admin.

Comment: not only to admin, you need to give read permission to everyone, if you need to open file as 'a' or 'w', then you need to give full control permission to everyone

Comment: actually, all users have full control

Comment: when wamp or something like that try to execute any script, it executes like guest user. so guest user also needs permission.

Comment: i think on error php returns negative value, your file might had open, try change if statement if($fp<0) and try to access the file

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

```
// Parse without sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
print_r($ini_array);

// Parse with sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
print_r($ini_array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fp = fopen (__DIR__ . "/filename.ini", "r");
```

See the list of magic constants: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Is the file there? It needs to be in the same directory - otherwise you need to adjust the argument.

Comment: Make sure that the file is actually named "filename.ini" and not "Filename.ini" or "filename.INI" - case matters.

Answer (score 0):

Just get content of INI file using Ajax Request.

don't need to PHP code for Run file.

PHP script will now work with .htm or .HTML file.

Comment: I create .htaccess file which contains: "AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm" to allow php working inside html

Comment: Can you please upload zip on some where ?
so i can review it. !

Comment: how can I send it to you? I will edit my question and put it there.